# I need to know how to open lshw, also known as Hardware Lister

Tags: hardware

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I find my hardware details?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details)

If you can't explain this to me then please direct me then please direct me to another hardware listing program.

Answer (score 1):

Open the dash. Then, search for Terminal. Open it. (It may be called Terminal Emulator).

Wait for a pronpt that looks like `user@computer:~$`. Then, type:

```
sudo lshw
```

and press Enter.

You will be prompted for your password. Give it(the space will remain blank, not even `******`), and press Enter. If the password is correct, the command will return results after a delay that can sometimes take a few minutes. You know it's finished when you see the `user@computer:~$` prompt again.