# How/Where do I get Ubuntu Drivers?

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, laptop, acer

I have an Acer Aspire 5745 laptop with all it's stock hardware, when I install Ubuntu 12.04.2 via windows installation it works, except for the drivers. There are no drivers installed, and I have spent the last 2 days looking for a place to download them.

Most sites I have found tell me what to do once I already HAVE the drivers, or give commands to an outdated version that no longer work.

First time linux user
please help

Comment: What drivers?.. what do you need drivers for?.

Comment: What symptoms are you having that lead you to suspect drivers?

Answer (score 2):

In linux, the drivers are included as a part of the kernel (device driver to be specific), usually, but not always, built as modules.

http://www.tldp.org/LDP/khg/HyperNews/get/devices/whatis.html

If you need assistance, please identify the hardware (video card, wireless card) you are having a problem with.

[How can I find my hardware details?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details)

Note: There are hardware devices for which there are no drivers (open source or proprietary) and in general you can not use windows drivers in Linux, although ndiswrapper does allow some windows drivers for wireless cards.