# How do you install a "device manager" on Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, software-recommendation

I want to check which drivers are running on my ubuntu 12.04 laptop. So I tried to install device manager. I typed `sudo apt-get install gnome-device-manager` but it returned a `gnome-device-manager not found`

So can anyone tell me how to install a device manager?

Comment: Dont u have inbuilt driver manager?.. press super key type Additional driver and select it..it is Ubuntu's default driver manager

Answer (score 6):

since that doens't work anymore you can take this device manager instead :

[Hardinfo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HardInfo)

by using : `sudo apt-get install hardinfo`

Answer (score 3):

Yeah there are various tools around but the most useful for diagnostic purposes tends to be the simplest. In our case we often ask people to post various outputs of `lspci` and `lsusb`.

For example `lspci -nnk | grep net -A2` shows us networking information, including the Kernel module (the driver):

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep net -A2
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
0a:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Motherboard [1458:e000]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

It doesn't need root and it doesn't need to be installed.

I cover more techniques in another question:

- [How can I find my hardware details?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't install gnome-device-manager, you can choose the same application. Sysinfo is an application that have function such as `gnome-device-manager`. You just type a command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get install sysinfo
```

Wait until the installation done. If was done, please run the program and you will see information about your device manager in Linux Ubuntu.

Comment: This doesn't work today.