# 13.10 upgrade dropping wifi

Tags: wireless, 13.10

Almost a complete newb here. After my last upgrade from 12.04 to 13.10 my wifi now randomly drops. The only way I can get a signal back is a shutdown and restart otherwise it shows no network is even available to connect to. Had no problems until the upgrade. Any help would be appreciated.

```
H/W path         Device      Class       Description
====================================================
                         system      h8-1534 (H2N64AA#ABA)
/0                           bus         2AC8
/0/0                         memory      64KiB BIOS
/0/4                         processor   AMD FX(tm)-6200 Six-Core Processor
/0/4/5                       memory      288KiB L1 cache
/0/4/6                       memory      6MiB L2 cache
/0/4/7                       memory      8MiB L3 cache
/0/d                         memory      10GiB System Memory
/0/d/0                       memory      DIMM Synchronous [empty]
/0/d/1                       memory      4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/d/2                       memory      2GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/d/3                       memory      4GiB DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0.6 ns)
/0/100                       bridge      RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (external gfx0 port B)
/0/100/0.2                   generic     RD990 I/O Memory Management Unit (IOMMU)
/0/100/2                     bridge      RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp  port B)
/0/100/2/0                   display     Turks PRO [Radeon HD 7570]
/0/100/2/0.1                 multimedia  Turks/Whistler HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6000  Series]
/0/100/5                     bridge      RD890 PCI to PCI bridge (PCI express gpp port E)
/0/100/5/0                   bus         TUSB73x0 SuperSpeed USB 3.0 xHCI Host Controller
/0/100/11                    storage     SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [RAID5 mode]
/0/100/12                    bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
/0/100/12.2                  bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
/0/100/13                    bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
/0/100/13.2                  bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
/0/100/14                    bus         SBx00 SMBus Controller
/0/100/14.2                  multimedia  SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)
/0/100/14.3                  bridge      SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller
/0/100/14.4                  bridge      SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge
/0/100/14.5                  bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
/0/100/15                    bridge      SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
/0/100/15.1                  bridge      SB700/SB800/SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1)
/0/100/15.2                  bridge      SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 2)
/0/100/15.2/0    wlan0       network     RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
/0/100/15.2/0.1              generic     RT3290 Bluetooth
/0/100/15.3                  bridge      SB900 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3)
/0/100/15.3/0    eth0        network     RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/16                    bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
/0/100/16.2                  bus         SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
/0/101                       bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 0
/0/102                       bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 1
/0/103                       bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 2
/0/104                       bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 3
/0/105                       bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 4
/0/106                       bridge      Family 15h Processor Function 5
/0/1             scsi0       storage     
/0/1/0.0.0       /dev/sda    disk        1TB WDC WD1002FAEX-0
/0/1/0.0.0/1                 volume      189MiB Windows FAT volume
/0/1/0.0.0/2     /dev/sda2   volume      244MiB data partition
/0/1/0.0.0/3     /dev/sda3   volume      931GiB LVM Physical Volume
/0/2             scsi2       storage     
/0/2/0.0.0       /dev/cdrom  disk        DVD A  DH16ACSHR
/0/3             scsi6       storage     
/0/3/0.0.0       /dev/sdb    disk        SCSI Disk
/0/3/0.0.1       /dev/sdc    disk        SCSI Disk
/0/3/0.0.2       /dev/sdd    disk        SCSI Disk
/0/3/0.0.3       /dev/sde    disk        MS/MS-Pro
/0/3/0.0.3/0     /dev/sde    disk        
/1                           power       Standard Efficiency
```

I apologize for my newbness. I hope this is enough info for the hardware. Thanks Bruno for pointing out I needed to add more info. If I am lacking anything else please let me know and I'll post it.

Comment: You need to give us more information about the kind of hardware you are using. http://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details

Comment: In particular please do `sudo lshw -c network`.

Comment: How did you got that output??? What we need is what poolie said or `sudo lspci -nnk | grep net -A2`.