# Why do cdimage.ubuntu.com and releases.ubuntu.com list different images?

Tags: system-installation, downloads, cd-image, ubuntu-website, history-of-ubuntu

There are two places I go when I want to download Ubuntu installer images: `cdimage.ubuntu.com` and `releases.ubuntu.com`.

Both of these appear equally official: they are both subdomains of `ubuntu.com`, and the main Ubuntu website makes references to both for its download links.  (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads uses the former for its 'Network installer' download links, and the latter for its 'BitTorrent' download links, for example.)

If I visit http://releases.ubuntu.com/ and follow links for the current Ubuntu release, I reach a page that lists numerous links to desktop and server installer images.  Likewise, if I visit http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ and follow links in a similar manner, I get to another very similar page that also gives numerous links to desktop and server installer images.  At the moment, these pages are:

- http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/
- http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/trusty/release/

(Following '14.04' links instead of 'trusty' leads to pages identical to the above, aside from their URLs.)

The language used on those two pages suggests that **each page lists all of the available image files**. For example, they each say "A full list of available files, including BitTorrent files, can be found below", and they each provide a wide variety of link types (`.iso`, `.torrent`, `.metalink` etc).

Neither page makes any reference to the other page's existence, and for a long time I thought that these were simply two different URLs serving essentially the same list of installer images.

Right?

---

Now that I look more closely I see that, despite appearances, **the actual lists of files are almost entirely different**.  For the Trusty release, `releases` serves `i386` and `amd64` images, whilst the `cdimage` site serves PowerPC and Mac-friendly images.  Even going back to the Precise release, when the architectures overlapped more, there are still installer images on each page that are not available from the other.

I've searched for explanations as to why the two sites are so disjoint, but have so far found none.

I assume that `releases.ubuntu.com` is intended to hold the more common installer images, whilst `cdimage.ubuntu.com` is intended to be a more comprehensive archive, given that it also hosts installers for the various spins such as Lubuntu, Xubuntu, etc.

However, this still doesn't explain some things:

- **Why is there no single page I can go to and see all available images?**  For example, if `releases.ubuntu.com` is reserved for the more popular images, why are these not also included in the (more comprehensive) list at `cdimage.ubuntu.com`?
- If there's a good reason for keeping them separate, then **why does neither page acknowledge the other as a complementary source of installer images?**
- **Is there any historical reason for this split?**

If anyone has any behind-the-scenes insight into this, I'd be interested to hear how things ended up this way.

Comment: Although I have no answer, thanks for pointing out the difference. I had only noticed it today and thought i386 had been abandoned.

Comment: could you place a description of your chipset here ?! what machine you have there and what bios exactly ? - http://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details - then list the details here ... - I assume that your hardware allow somehow mirroring datas for else purposes ?! - (hidden flash-disk ?) -

Comment: @dschinn1001: did you mean to add that comment here?  This is a question about how files are arranged on the Ubuntu servers, not a request for help in finding an installer for any specific machine.

Answer (score 7):

The 1st page of [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) seems to me to explain why:

> ## Ubuntu Releases
>
> The following releases of Ubuntu are available:
>
> - [Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/utopic/)
>
>   [Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (Trusty Tahr)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/)
>
>   [Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy Salamander)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/saucy/)
>
>   [Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/raring/)
>
>   [Ubuntu 12.10 (Quantal Quetzal)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/)
>
>   [Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS (Precise Pangolin)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/precise/)
>
>   [Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS (Lucid Lynx)](http://releases.ubuntu.com/lucid/)
>
> We are happy to provide hosting for the following projects via the
>   [cdimage server](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/). While they are not
>   commercially supported by Canonical, they receive full support from their
>   communities.
>
> - [Edubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/edubuntu/releases/)
>
>   [Kubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/)
>
>   [Lubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/)
>
>   [Mythbuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/mythbuntu/releases/)
>
>   [Ubuntu GNOME](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-gnome/releases/)
>
>   [UbuntuKylin](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntukylin/releases/)
>
>   [UbuntuStudio](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntustudio/releases/)
>
>   [Xubuntu](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/)
>
> The cdimage server also hosts releases of other Ubuntu images not found on
>   this server, such as builds for less popular architectures and other non-standard
>   and unsupported images.  For Ubuntu Desktop and Server on popular architectures,
>   please see the links above instead.
>
> - [Unsupported Ubuntu Images](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/)
>
> For old releases, see
>   [old-releases.ubuntu.com](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/).

- [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

  Contains only current commercially supported *releases* images (i386 & amd64 only, 5 years period max LTS for server editions).
- [old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/)

  Old *releases* images that no longer supported.
- [cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/)

  Commercially unsupported *favors* and *builds* including alpha, beta and daily builds.
- [cloud-images.ubuntu.com](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/), old sub-domain is still working too [uec-images.ubuntu.com](http://uec-images.ubuntu.com)

  > Ubuntu Cloud Images are pre-installed disk images that have been customized by Ubuntu engineering to run on cloud-platforms such as Amazon EC2, Openstack, Windows and LXC.

  It was there in 2010 as shown in the history of [UEC/Images Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images), [Revision 2 as of 2010-08-19 20:59:56](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEC/Images?action=recall&rev=2).

As canonical is a company that provides technical support, it should have should have such kind of separation.

Looking to the official links on [www.ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/). They are all point to [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/) except [Network installer](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads) and [Ubuntu Kylin](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu-kylin).

Another thing, they always try to minimize mirror size and mirroring daily builds just wasting of resources. [Mirror script](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Mirrors/Scripts) point only to [releases.ubuntu.com](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

I couldn't find out any official note about such decision yet. But separation between *releases* and other *builds* back to 2005 at least. See [Ubuntu Server Project Unleashed!](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2005-December/000047.html). Even back to Oct 2004 with release of Ubuntu 4.10 which is [the first release](https://askubuntu.com/questions/520451/what-was-the-first-ubuntu-release-with-a-live-cd-feature)(just i386), Make a look on these few early mails from [ubuntu-announce archive](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2004-October/date.html).

Comment: Hmm. That page was modified around June 2013, prior to which it simply said "other images". Do you have any posts or such indicating when or why this split was formalized?

Comment: @muru, It seems not possible to get any thing in the archives (mail lists & wiki). as both hosts were used from the beginning with 1st release of Ubuntu, please see my last edit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the effort! I'll keep the bounty open a little while longer to see if anything pops up, if you don't mind.

Comment: you are welcome, sure no problem at all

Comment: Now it seems to be possible to find "official" installers (the same but running older versions...)

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, `release.ubuntu.com` is intended to hold more common installer image, whereas `cdimage.ubuntu.com` is for other images, like PowerPC or Kubuntu.

In my opinion, Canonical intended to split installers based on their popularity, since Ubuntu installer images are usually distributed using mirrors. Operators of mirror services can choose  what type of mirror they want to copy.

For example, http://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu-releases/ (Ubuntu mirror "University of Waterloo Computer Science Club") has images of `releases.ubuntu.com` and there is a link for cdimage server.