# How to know what is the model of my wireless card?

Tags: wireless, command-line, drivers, interface, lspci

I am looking for command line which tells me what is the model of my wireless card? For example if that is Atheors. The result should be atheros.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To find the model of your wireless card:

```
lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

The pipe symbol | is on the right side of my keyboard on the same key with backslash. We added -nn because we want numerical details, particularly the pci.id, that may help diagnose a problem. [0280](http://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PD/02) is the class used by *lspci* for wireless devices: for example:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection [8086:4227] (rev 02)
```

Are you looking for just Atheros with all other details removed?

Comment: if there may be some extra information, that will be better

Comment: what is nn and why 0280?

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: I said, Not strictly Atheros, if the command shows some extra information that will be fine.please take a look to the second command thanks

Comment: @chili555 In my case is `0200`: `03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)`. So, I suggest to use better `lspci -nn | grep Wireless`

Comment: @RaduRădeanu There are a very few cases where lspci classifies a device as 0200 which is usually ethernet. On the other hand, there are a very few wireless devices that don't actually use the word 'Wireless' in the description. Here is an example: 01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01) I suspect there may be no completely failsafe answer. 0280 will get 98% of devices.

Comment: @chili555 Actually, there is: [`lspci -nnk | grep net -A2`](http://askubuntu.com/a/31625/147044).

Comment: This commands gets my ethernet device but not wireless.