# no internet on 14.04

Tags: internet

All explanations require an internet connection for updates. This Ubuntu installation allows no way to acquire an internet connection. How can I install the proper ethernet and wifi drivers to make this OS work?

Comment: start by identifying your hardware. - http://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details

Comment: Acer aspire has good wifi and ethernet connections with XP, but nothing with installed Ubuntu. I had a strong wifi connection with the live CD but it all fell apart after the install.