# I am getting "windows on malware" behavior when browsing on firefox

Tags: firefox, 17.04, malware

My CPU: AMD FX 8320(8core), Ram, 16GB DDR3 @2133, GPU:GTX 650 ti and I use an Intel SSD for ubuntu (no other OS on the machine).

My ubuntu version is 17.04 64bit
kernel version is 4.10.0.3
Firefox is 56 64bit.

My computer used to run older iterations of ubuntu flawlessly it was snappy and did not have any issues.

All my software is up to date (and I use the latest proprietary drivers for GPU and CPU)

It used to run this version of ubuntu the same way.. but for the last month or so I face some serious issues.

For example when I try to enter text like I am doing now to post this question it lags behind (from a few ms most usually up to a few seconds!)

Initially I thought some sort of updated file was buggy and just waited for a new update to fix it but the longer I wait my computer gets even worse instead of better.

And generally waiting times are increased... I also noticed that the refresh icon sometimes doesnt appear (in the address-bar of firefox) and only the "X" icon is there instead but the tab is not loading anything new and the webpage seems visually complete. (that gets fixed some times but not every time  by hitting F5)

Youtube videos can be choppy and I need to refresh the page or full-size and minimize to make them work normal (also sometimes the controls like playpause lag as well for example I click on play or on maximize and it does it after a good 1-3 seconds) My computer used to be able to play 4k resolution without any issue and now that happens on "simple" 1080p.

The filemanager icon on unity task-bar seems to have a loading bar on it sometimes when I copy a file but stays there forever after.. (I need to restart the computer to make it disappear) and generally my system is not snappy.

And this was a fresh instal (not an upgrade) which is a few months old and I didnt touch anything in particular on the settings.

Do I have malware for linux? what could I check? Is there any software to help me out/scan my computer?

Comment: The likely hood you have any sort of malware is extremely low and not every problem is due to malware. Identify your hardware and how much RAM you have. Checking for malware is not automated and on a compromised system next to impossible. You would have to scan from a live CD. See http://www.caine-live.net/ and similar tools.

Comment: "Identify your hardware and how much RAM you have" I have already done that in the first line of my post I have 16 GB of low latency high frequency RAM as for checking for malware I know that it is not easy thats why I made this post to get ideas on what or how to check... the tool you suggest has features to analyze windows based OSes I am facing the problems i describe above when using ubuntu not windows.. anyway thanks for taking some of your time to post me a response.

Comment: My points are forenics is complex regardless of OS and that we need more information about your hardware. https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details . We need lspci for the major things (graphics and networking as well as drivers in use) and for memory we need the output of `free -m`. You could run debsums - https://www.tecmint.com/check-verify-md5sum-packages-files-in-linux/ and create a new user to start . That would at least check your system and user files.