# Mic doesn't record on Linux

Tags: lenovo, microphone

I have bought a Lenovo Ideapad 330 and the mic records on Windows, but when I have instaled Linux (Ubuntu Budgie, Mint, Deepin, Elementary Os...) the mic doesn't record on browsers. The audio is recorded locally in my desktop, but not in the browser.

I have configured in my desktop:

[Budgie Sound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQdwk.png)

[Alsa Mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ju22u.png)

[Pulse Audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q0X7c.png)

And in the applications, e.g, Meet:

[Meet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYYvg.png)

[Meet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYOzc.png)

I can just hear wheezing coming from the call. I have tried Google Chrome, Chromium, Firefox, Opera and Vivid.

**Obs** ¹: Ideapad 330 has only one input that works for output (headphone) and input (microphone) devices

**Obs** ²: I have updated everything and by now I'm on Ubuntu Budgie 19

**Obs** ³: I have also try to install a specific driver for the Realtek device, but I did not find the driver in their [site](https://www.realtek.com/en/) (in the alsa mixer a generic driver is informed, not the specific version)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed Windows 10 and installed [Deepin](https://www.deepin.org/pt/download/) 15.9, after that I have set the Alsa Mixer PPA on `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
## Alsa Mixer
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu bionic main

deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/alsa-daily/ubuntu bionic main
```

And Webupd 8 PPA:

```
## Webpd 8
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu bionic main
```

I have `upgrade` the system and then installed `pavucontrol`, after that I have open the `pavucontrol` and set the following configuration (the channels can't be locked and one channel need to be lower than the other) to the microphone:

[Microphone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygC7V.png)

I have `reboot` the system and tested the microphone on browser and locally, it worked. I have read and try many alternatives for a few days, I hope it help you too.

Obs ¹: The Lenovo forum there's nothing related to this problem, they don't provide Linux drivers, the Real Tek site it's totally broken and if you try to call Lenovo they won't give you any support. Don't buy a Lenovo device!

Obs ²: On Linux Mint a lot of devices werem showed on `alsamixer` CLI, but in Deepin only the real devices werem showed as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEYH0.png) and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YRcK2.png). If you want the config files of Pulse Audio open my repository on Github [here](https://github.com/Sphinxs/Openbox).

Obs ³: On Linux Mint I have try to unmute the devices using the arrow keys and the key `m`, and then save the config using `sudo alsactl store`, but for some reason the config always returned to the default (muted)

Comment: Hi Walter, Lenovo C740, Deepin 20. The microphone is not working at all in all the applications. Do you have any suggestions? Also, my fingerprint reader is not recognised at all.

Comment: Hi, Ara. In Lenovo case I would try to load Windows (not sure if Wine or Virtualbox works) and use the Lenovo Vantage to update the bios, besides Orbit to update the drivers and verify using the Windows update tool, if you don't want to try this, try to install [extra drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-additional-drivers), [check the hardware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details) that your device has and go to the manufacturer site and search for the driver (e.g Real Tek)...