# My audio volume gets automatically increased to its maximum after 2 seconds

Tags: sound

I have a self-assembled machine consisting of :

1. Motherboard: MSI x470 with Realtek ALC892 chipset
2. RAM: 16GB Corsair Vengeance DDR4
3. Storage: SSD 1TB Samsung Evo 970
4. Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070
5. CPU: AMD Ryzen 2600x

I have a dual-boot installation of Windows 10 Professional, and Ubuntu 18.0.2 LTS.

Earlier today, I had an issue with my audio volume where it kept going down automatically and get fixed at 42/100 every 2 seconds, even after I increase it myself.

So while looking up for a solution online, I stumbled upon an answer here and tried the solution. The problem didn't get resolved, however, but instead it reversed: now the volume automatically shifts back up to the maximum no matter how I change it.

What could the problem be?

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it might be a similar problem as the one I dealt with and provided a solution for previously in [Audio volume doesn't change](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1119938/audio-volume-doesnt-change/1121581#1121581) in any case, please check if

```
pactl load-module module-alsa-sink control=PCM
```

creates a new device in `pavucontrol` (the pulseaudio volume manager) and adjusting the new output volume behaves correctly.