# Lenovo (yoga) slim 7 pro volume cannot be changed

Tags: volume-control

I just bought the brand new Lenovo (Yoga) Slim 7 Pro Gen 8 (AMD, 14.5 inch).

I didn't face any major incompatibility when installing Ubuntu 23.04, except for one: it seems that I can't set the volume. It's really loud of the box, I can mute it, but I can't increase/decrease it (when pressing the volume buttons, I see a display telling me that the volume is being changed but it doesn't have any actual impact). Going to the settings, it seems that sliding the System Volume control does have any impact on the actual volume coming out of the speakers. The only way to reduce the volume seems to be to modify the Volume Levels for each app, which works as expected.

I just downloaded and installed Ubuntu this morning, so the install is as fresh as it could be. I also tried installing both Pop OS and Zorin OS and faced the same issue.

Did anyone face the same issue with maybe a different (lenovo) laptop? Should I return the laptop while I still have the opportunity to do so?

Thank you!

Comment: I've opened a bug on ubuntu launchpad. See here: [https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/2048398](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/2048398)

Answer (score 7):

After a lot of research, it seems that the following solved my problem:

https://askubuntu.com/a/1204558/1692864

Apparently, when using alsamixer, the master volume was indeed being triggered by the volume keys of the laptops but the PCM volume was immediately increasing to 100%, even at the first volume level. This directly set the volume of the speakers to 100%.

The trick was to actually locate the analog-output.conf.common file with a pipewire configuration (I found it in this folder: `/usr/share/alsa-card-profile/mixer/paths/`) and add those three lines at the beginning of the file:

```
[Element Master]
switch = mute
volume = ignore
```

And reboot the laptop.

Comment: This is not a compete answer. What do you do once you find that file?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I just updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing what you've learned! Generally, when linking to another site, we expect an answer to describe the specific steps that were needed, in case the external page disappears. It happens, even for big sites like Microsoft. When linking to another AskUbuntu post, that post could get deleted in some cases, although that's rare for good answers to good questions. It's still better to write down exactly what worked for you, so others seeking help can learn from your perspective.

Comment: The right file is /usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common in my case (instead /usr/share/alsa-card-profile/mixer/paths/analog-output.conf.common) [Ubuntu 22.04]

Comment: This works, but how to ensure that it stays like this. Every update I have to redo these changes as the update overwrites it.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder, if [this last week merged fix `634e5e1e06f5c ("ALSA: hda/realtek: Add quirk for Lenovo Yoga Pro 7")`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=634e5e1e06f5cdd614a1bc429ecb243a51cc009d) is a solution for the reported problem. I will be in upcoming kernel 6.7.