# Lenovo YOGA 7i Intel i7-13700H - Cannot change volume on the speakers

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, alsa, lenovo

UPDATE: I've opened a bug on ubuntu launchpad. See here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/2048398

I bought a new Lenovo Yoga 7i - Intel i7 13700-H, with a fresh installation of the latest Ubuntu 23.04.

Everything works fine. The only problem is that I cannot change the volume of the laptop's speakers, i.e. the volume is always at maximum level. Moreover, I can mute the speakers.

Note that the Bluetooth works perfectly (I can instantly pair devices and control the volume).

I came across a similar question ([Lenovo (yoga) slim 7 pro volume cannot be changed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466286/lenovo-yoga-slim-7-pro-volume-cannot-be-changed)) but the solution does not work for me.

What can I do?

Hw information:

```
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel vendor: Lenovo driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    bus-ID: 00:1f.3
  Sound API: ALSA v: k6.2.0-39-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-1: PulseAudio v: 16.1 running: no
  Sound Server-2: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 running: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try alsamixer or kmix volume mixer.

Select your card from the volume mixer app.

Also there is Pulseaudio volume control app, change audio profile from there.

Comment: nope, changing pulsuadio mixer doesn't fix the problem. Also, ideally, I want to be able to control the audio through the slider on the quick-access menu.