# Check my Hardware status

Tags: software-installation, hardware, maintenance

Is there any software I can use to check the status and wear of my hardware?

For example the status of my SSDs.

Comment: Please, have you tried searching for anything on Google about this?

Comment: Also see: [How can I find my hardware details?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31618/how-can-i-find-my-hardware-details)

Answer (score 0):

### For HDD/SSD

You can use GNOME Disks.
If it is not installed, install it with `sudo apt install gnome-disks`.

Now select your SSD, and open SMART DATA & Self-Tests.

[image: smart]

There you can start the self-test.

### For Batteries

You can check the health of your laptop's battery in the power settings. It depends on the desktop environment.
In XFCE, you can open settings manager -> power manager.
[image: battery]