# Linux equivalent of msinfo32

Tags: system-info

Apart from lspci or dmesg in terminal, is there a tool with more of a GUI to list the hardware/software in my system in greater detail?

Comment: There is `lshw`. There is a GUI too, but why would you need it?

Comment: Probably answered here https://askubuntu.com/a/31625/130807

Comment: There are times when I look at stuff in terminal and its just a wall of text and I feel somewhat confused at what I am looking at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe package hardinfo is that you are looking for. It has a gui and gives detailed infos . Sorry for german text.

[image: hardinfo]

Comment: I just tried this, it still gives me a lot of extraneous information when I click on generate report and isn't as concise as your image above, did you use some particular setting?  But this is pretty much what I was after.

Comment: No i use it out of the box without any changes on default settings. And i do not generate reports . I only start the application and click  around in the modules.

Answer (score 2):

There is `lshw-gtk` that will show all hardware in GUI.

You can install it by

```
sudo apt install lshw-gtk
```

If you can do it without GUI, you can simply run `lshw` in a terminal and see the same information.

Comment: I get an error, I presume I need to reload my system because I have installed and uninstalled a bunch of stuff and borked/recovered the system more than once so I guess this is to be expected: (lshw-gtk:27366): IBUS-WARNING **: Unable to connect to ibus: Unexpected lack of content trying to read a line

Answer (score 1):

Hardware & software documentation script, one line using && \ to make as one entry

https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/system-info/raw/main/system-info && \
chmod +x system-info && \
./system-info
```

And lots more detail on Wireless:

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && \
chmod +x wireless-info && \
./wireless-info
```

Comment: This ran with errors, but I think I like "nobody" answer the best so far as it worked without error and looks far nicer